# How can I apply Laravel's polymorph-system to what seems to be reversed

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, database-design, eloquent-relationship

#### Background

In our Laravel system, we have a Post which is e.g. either a VideoPost or a TextPost (the type is stored in a `type`-attribute). Every Post (no matter what type it is) depends on translations, so we have made every Post have a PostTranslation, which contains a one-to-many relation to VideoPostTranslation or TextPostTranslation.

This means that for me to access the translated content of the Post, I first have to fetch the Post, then check the type, and fetch both the relevant PostTranslations and whatever sub-type it is (e.g. VideoPostTranslation).

We've now realized that this is sub-optimal, and we're hoping to get some help on how this can be achieved.

#### Goal

We want to transform our database to something like so:

```
[Post]
int: id
str: type // one of [video, text]

[VideoPostTranslation]
int: id
int: post_id
str: language_code
str: video_specific_data

[TextPostTranslation]
int: id
int: parent_id
str: language_code
str: text_specific_data
```

In this structure, there is no redundant data, and hopefully it's possible to get Laravel to help us with the querying of this.

Preferrably, we want to be able to write something like the following:

```
$posts = Post::with('translations')->get();

foreach($posts as $post) {
  switch($post->type) {
    case 'video': 
      // handle $post->translations[]->video_specific_data
    case 'text':
      // handle $post->translations[]->text_specific_data
  }
}
```

We've seen that Laravel has a good system for morphing between classes, but it generally requires that the one containing the type-data is also the one which handles the morphing. In their one-to-many example, they use a commentable-system, where a Comment can refer to both Posts and Videos through the `commentable`-relation, but I'm not sure how this would work in our case.

This, for example, will not work:

```
class Post extends Model
{
  public function translations()
  {
    return $this->morphTo();
  }
}

class VideoPostTranslation extends Model
{
  public function post()
  {
    return $this->morphMany(Post::class, 'translations');
  }
}

class TextPostTranslation extends Model
{
  public function post()
  {
    return $this->morphMany(Post::class, 'translations');
  }
}
```

What changes do we need to "implement"? Do we need to add an intermediary many-to-many table called PageTranslation to handle the the relationship? Or is it possible to get Laravel to work with the proposed database structure?

Answer (score 0):

Your relationships look fine to me and it should work. **Could you please explain further** how it doesn't work and what error do you get. Futher, the `switch` statement in the provided `foreach` loop may not neccessary. Instead of

> ```
> foreach($posts as $post) {
>   switch($post->type) {
>     case 'video': 
>       // handle $post->translations[]->video_specific_data
>     case 'text':
>       // handle $post->translations[]->text_specific_data
>   }
> }
> ```

You can directly access its translated model via the name of the relationship. Pass the language key to retrieve a specific languague translation.

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    $post->translations()->where('language_code', $langKey)->first()->content;
}
```

In the case where `video_post_translations` and `text_post_translations`  have their distinctive fields, such as `video_post_translations` has a `video`, where in `text_post_translations` table, this `video` field is not present (which is very likely), a `switch case` can be used.

And if the `switch case` is used anyway, consider grouping `video_post_translations` and `text_post_translations` table, which definitely simplify the problem since `posts.type` has differentiated needed fields. Depends on your need this approach may not be suitable.

Comment: I have tested with the proposed db-structure as well as model-code, and it does not currently work. I know that for this to work as Laravel intended, we'd need the polymorph relation to go the other way, e.g. meaning that one post would need to refer to one VideoPageVersion, by both specifying `type` as well as `id`. I realize that it's solvable with a pivot-table, so I suppose we'll just have to try that.